# Displaying two sections that are different sizes side by side html

Tags: html, css

Here is the html coding:

```
<div>        
    <section class="aboutus">
        <div>Some content 1</div>
        <div>Some more 1</div>
    </section>

    <section class="tripinfo">
        <div>Some content 2</div>
        <div>Some more 2</div>
    </section>
</div>
```

I want to display to html sections side by side.
When I do this it works:

```
div {float: left;}
div section {width: 50%; float: left;}
```

but when i  try to specify each one as a separate size like this it doesnt:

```
div {
    float: left;
}
section .aboutus{
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
}
section .tripinfo{
    float: left;
    width: 20%
}
```

As you can see.  In the first example i make both section 50 percent in the same code block.  However as soon as i specify the size of each on in different classes it screws up.
So if any of you could help me out that would be great.

Comment: Don't use float. Instead use flexbox or CSS grid for aligning elements in a page.

Comment: What @HarshitDamani said, but further, check out Bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/); it's awesome.

Comment: I was agreeing with the idea of using a grid pattern, which is obviously used by Bootstrap.

Comment: @JacobBarnes I see. I believe when Harshit mentioned "CSS grid", he was referring to the actual *[CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)*, which is also a neat little way to position elements. That being said, I do believe that bootstrap might be a bit excessive in this particular instance but is a helpful tool.

Comment: For one dimensional rows, flexbox serves the purpose of cleanly managing and styling the elements in contrast to float which might be easier when working with just a few elements but may/maynot cause alignment problems as it gets complex. And as for why I mentioned CSS grid, that should be obvious. It's the true way of aligning anything from simple to complex!

Comment: **your selector is wrong**. you want: `section.tripinfo` and `section.aboutus`, not `section .tripinfo` and `section .aboutus` since section and class are the same elements :)  try: `section.aboutus{
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
}
section.tripinfo{
    float: left;
    width: 20%
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out using Flexbox instead of floats.

```css
#container{
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

#container section {
  padding: 10px;
}

.aboutus{
  background: #CCC;
  width: 80%;
}

.tripinfo {
  background: #DDD;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">        
    <section class="aboutus">
        <div>Some content 1</div>
        <div>Some more 1</div>
    </section>

    <section class="tripinfo">
        <div>Some content 2</div>
        <div>Some more 2</div>
        <div>Some more 2</div>
        <div>Some more 2</div>
        <div>Some more 2</div>
        <div>Some more 2</div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: that worked thank you. I will mark the answer as solved when it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex` instead using `float`, it will be a lot easier and less lines of code.

You html and css should be :

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.aboutus {
  width: 80%;
  background: grey;
}

tripinfo {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">        
    <section class="aboutus">
        <div>Some content 1</div>
        <div>Some more 1</div>
    </section>

    <section class="tripinfo">
        <div>Some content 2</div>
        <div>Some more 2</div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to right tick the answer and upvote it if you feel it is right

Answer (score 0):

add this property to div element

```
display:inline;
```

if it does not work then remove float:left from div and add float:left to first section and display:inline to both section

Comment: `inline-block`, not `inline`!

Answer (score 0):

Seeing some answers with nice suggestions, but nobody has really pointed out what's actually wrong with your example.

1. You don't need the `div {float: left;}`. It's applying to every single div on the page and causing some funky behavior.
2. A space in a CSS selector indicates *descendant*, therefore the selector `section .class` is applying to any `.class` that is a *descendant* of a `section`. If you want it to apply to elements that are both `section` *and* `.class`, remove the space, like so:  `section.class`
3. Floats require `clear`s. After each level of floated elements, you need to include a `clear: both;` to ensure that elements afterwards will still display properly. This is easier achieved by doing a `::after` pseudo-element, so you don't have to actually put another element on the page to clear.

An updated example:

```css
div.float-container::after {
    clear: both;
}

section.aboutus{
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
}
section.tripinfo{
    float: left;
    width: 20%
}
```

```html
<div class="float-container">        
    <section class="aboutus">
        <div>Some content 1</div>
        <div>Some more 1</div>
    </section>

    <section class="tripinfo">
        <div>Some content 2</div>
        <div>Some more 2</div>
    </section>
</div>
```

`display: flex` makes things easier in almost all cases, but it isn't *always* the answer. I truly feel that sometimes a `float` is just a quicker and more concise approach to achieving a simple result.